# Windows Process Fails with ExitCode = -1073741819 when Executing PS Script

Tags: windows, powershell, ssis, process

I have a PowerShell script which executes some logic. If I run that script using PowerShell ISE, code works fine and no error is generated. If I run the same code using SSIS which creates Windows Process which calls that same script, under same credentials, it fails with an exit code -1073741819 and without any error from the process (p.StandardError is empty - check the code below).

Sample code:

```cs
p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = <path_to_powershell.exe>;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File \"<powershell_script_path>\"";

p.Start();

string stderr = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
string stdout = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

var processExited = p.WaitForExit(10800000);

int succ = (p.ExitCode != 0 || stderr.Length > 0 || !processExited) ? 0 : 1;

// Here it fails because p.ExitCode is not 0 but -1073741819
```

This same code works fine for several other scripts, but it fails for this one script for some reason. As I explained earlier, if I run this same script manually, it works fine.

Comment: Reference the status code as a non-negative, hexadecimal value. -1073741819 is 0xC0000005, i.e. `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`.

Comment: I checked Event Viewer and I think I know what is the issue - antivirus!

```Faulting application name: powershell.exe, version: 10.0.14393.206, time stamp: 0x57daccf5
Faulting module name: HIPHandlers64.dll, version: 10.6.0.9246, time stamp: 0x5ccff778
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Faulting process id: 0x2d44
Faulting application start time: 0x01d50efb4a02dad2
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\McAfee\Endpoint Security\Threat Prevention\Ips\HIPHandlers64.dll```

Comment: @knyazs We're also facing the same problem. Can you please tells us how did you resolve this.

Comment: It was some time ago, but I believe we just disabled antivirus on PowerShell folder.